# Update value of a column in postgres into lower case

Tags: django, postgresql, model

I have a table name **service_table** which have some fields. A field have days name like **Sunday**, **Monday**, **Tuesday** etc.. I want to change all the column value in postgres database table into lower case.
For Instance
**'Sunday'** update as **'sunday'**
I am written a query

```
update service_table set days=lower(days);
```

but it shows

> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

**Note:** This table has some foreign key.

Comment: what is datatype of column for service_table

Comment: What is the **exact** data type of column `days`?

Comment: Please add the whole error message, not just the hint part.

Comment: data type is:svc_days = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10), size=7)

Comment: Hey! I am using postgres command prompt. There is only hint occurred.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Django shell

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

service_table.objects.update(days=Lower(F('days'))
```

Django `update()` is a bulk operation for direct updates.

Django `F()` makes it possible to refer to model field values and perform database operations using them without actually having to pull them out of the database into Python memory.

`F()` helps to pull the model field value, then it process to the requirement and use `update()` to save it back

Comment: Good answer from a new member. It would be even bettter if you added an explaination as to what happens here.